# Implementing a JavaScript AudioNode

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Is it possible to implement a custom [AudioNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode) with the Web Audio API?

I would like to build a node that will contain several other nodes (ChannelSplitters and AnalyserNodes).  Ideally, I will be able to connect to this custom node like any other AudioNode.  For example,

```
var customNode = new CustomNode();
mediaStreamSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(userMedia);

// This will not work, as I need to know what to implement in CustomNode
mediaStreamSource.connect(customNode);
customNode.connect(context.destination);
```

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode#Methods), an AudioNode implements an [EventTarget interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget).  Is that all that is used for shuffling audio around?  And if so, how can implement this interface in a way to handle audio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a custom echo node with web-audio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702733/creating-a-custom-echo-node-with-web-audio)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AudioNode class file

```
"use strict";

var AudioNode = global.AudioNode;
var AudioNode$connect;
var AudioNode$disconnect;

function connect() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);

  if (args.length && typeof args[0].__connectFrom === "function") {
    args[0].__connectFrom.apply(args[0], [ this ].concat(args.slice(1)));
  } else {
    AudioNode$connect.apply(this, args);
  }
}

function disconnect() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);

  if (args.length && typeof args[0].__disconnectFrom === "function") {
    args[0].__disconnectFrom.apply(args[0], [ this ].concat(args.slice(1)));
  } else {
    AudioNode$disconnect.apply(this, args);
  }
}

function use() {
  if (typeof AudioNode !== "undefined" && AudioNode.prototype.connect !== connect) {
    AudioNode$connect = AudioNode.prototype.connect;
    AudioNode$disconnect = AudioNode.prototype.disconnect;

    AudioNode.prototype.connect = connect;
    AudioNode.prototype.disconnect = disconnect;
  }
}

function unuse() {
  if (typeof AudioNode !== "undefined" && AudioNode.prototype.connect === connect) {
    AudioNode.prototype.connect = AudioNode$connect;
    AudioNode.prototype.disconnect = AudioNode$disconnect;
  }
}

module.exports = {
  use: use,
  unuse: unuse,
};
```

AudioNode test file

```
"use strict";

var assert = require("power-assert");
var PowerAudioNode = require("../");

function CustomAudioNode(audioContext) {
  this.audioContext = audioContext;
  this.gain1 = audioContext.createGain();
  this.gain2 = audioContext.createGain();
  this.inlet = this.gain1;
  this.outlet = this.gain2;
}

CustomAudioNode.prototype.connect = function() {
  this.gain1.connect(this.gain2);
  this.gain2.connect.apply(this.gain2, arguments);
};

CustomAudioNode.prototype.disconnect = function() {
  this.gain1.disconnect();
  this.gain2.disconnect.apply(this.gain2, arguments);
};

CustomAudioNode.prototype.__connectFrom = function(source) {
  source.connect(this.gain1);
};

CustomAudioNode.prototype.__disconnectFrom = function(source) {
  source.disconnect();
};

describe("PowerAudioNode", function() {
  describe("use(): void", function() {
    before(PowerAudioNode.use);
    before(PowerAudioNode.use);
    it("works", function() {
      var audioContext = new global.AudioContext();
      var oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
      var customAudioNode = new CustomAudioNode(audioContext);
      var compressor = audioContext.createDynamicsCompressor();

      oscillator.connect(customAudioNode);
      customAudioNode.connect(compressor);
      compressor.connect(audioContext.destination);

      assert(audioContext.destination.$isConnectedFrom(compressor));
      assert(compressor.$isConnectedFrom(customAudioNode.outlet));
      assert(customAudioNode.inlet.$isConnectedFrom(oscillator));

      oscillator.disconnect(customAudioNode);
      customAudioNode.disconnect();
      compressor.disconnect();

      assert(!audioContext.destination.$isConnectedFrom(compressor));
      assert(!compressor.$isConnectedFrom(customAudioNode.outlet));
      assert(!customAudioNode.inlet.$isConnectedFrom(oscillator));
    });
  });
  describe("unuse(): void", function() {
    before(PowerAudioNode.unuse);
    it("works", function() {
      var audioContext = new global.AudioContext();
      var oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
      var customAudioNode = new CustomAudioNode(audioContext);
      var compressor = audioContext.createDynamicsCompressor();

      assert.throws(function() {
        oscillator.connect(customAudioNode);
      });
      customAudioNode.connect(compressor);
      compressor.connect(audioContext.destination);

      assert(audioContext.destination.$isConnectedFrom(compressor));
      assert(compressor.$isConnectedFrom(customAudioNode.outlet));
      assert(!customAudioNode.inlet.$isConnectedFrom(oscillator));

      oscillator.disconnect();
      customAudioNode.disconnect();
      compressor.disconnect();

      assert(!audioContext.destination.$isConnectedFrom(compressor));
      assert(!compressor.$isConnectedFrom(customAudioNode.outlet));
      assert(!customAudioNode.inlet.$isConnectedFrom(oscillator));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice idea!  Thanks for the post.

Comment: FYI, for anyone curious, I found this code in a module here:  https://github.com/mohayonao/power-audio-node  @targunp Did you write this?  If not, you should give credit to the original author, mohayonao.

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/jamwithchrome-audio/) seems to have a method for doing just what you're looking for.

Basic premise:

```
function MyCustomNode(){
  this.input = audioContext.createGainNode();
  var output = audioContext.createGainNode();
  this.connect = function(target){
     output.connect(target);
  };
}
```

Example:

```
function AudioBus(){
  this.input = audioContext.createGainNode();
  var output = audioContext.createGainNode();
  var custom = new MyCustomNode();

  this.input.connect(custom);
  custom.connect(output);

  this.connect = function(target){
     output.connect(target);
  };
}

//create some native oscillators and our custom audio bus
var bus = new AudioBus(),
    instrument1 = audioContext.createOscillator(),
    instrument2 = audioContext.createOscillator(),
    instrument3 = audioContext.createOscillator();

//connect our instruments to the same bus
instrument1.connect(bus.input);
instrument2.connect(bus.input);
instrument3.connect(bus.input);
bus.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

**Edit:** The question could be a possible duplicate of [Creating a custom echo node with web-audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702733/creating-a-custom-echo-node-with-web-audio), but I believe the answer you're looking for is [the one from @MattDiamond](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733639/1397319). It's not exactly a *pretty* solution, but it seems to get the job done:

```
function FeedbackDelayNode(context, delay, feedback){
  this.delayTime.value = delay;
  this.gainNode = context.createGainNode();
  this.gainNode.gain.value = feedback;
  this.connect(this.gainNode);
  this.gainNode.connect(this);
}

function FeedbackDelayFactory(context, delayTime, feedback){
  var delay = context.createDelayNode(delayTime + 1);
  FeedbackDelayNode.call(delay, context, delayTime, feedback);
  return delay;
}

AudioContext.prototype.createFeedbackDelay = function(delay, feedback){
  return FeedbackDelayFactory(this, delay, feedback);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm doing now.  What I'd like to do though is have a custom node that another node can connect to directly.  In your example, I would use `instrument1.connect(bus)` instead of `instrument1.connect(bus.input)`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Brad yeah I totally understand that. I was playing around with the `AudioNode` prototype chain, but no matter how I tried extending it I always ended up with `Illegal Invocation` errors whenever I'd try connecting the nodes together. I'd wager that it's not possible to get this working as all of the native `AudioNode` types are instantiated with the `AudioContext` instance create[*NodeType*] method. I'd imagine that's where the magic happens.